# advanced search with ElasticSerach

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've create a small application with PHP and I use ES. 
My request is good, but I've got the good result.
My request look-like that:

> link:9200/index/_search?from=0&size=130&q=try:'yes'
>   %2Bbrand:'BMW' %2Bmodel:'SERIE 5' %2Bprice:[500 TO 700000]

When I send this query, ES reply me with model 'SERIE 3' and 'SERIE 5', it's great, but when I send this query, I would like to recover only 'BMW' and 'SERIE 5'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How is your "model" field indexed? is it analyzed? Does the relevance of your search have any importance, or do you just want to filter the documents on these values?

Comment: I use this simple définition in my map:  ""model": {
"type": "string"
},"

Answer (score 1):

First, you should take a look at the documentation to be more familiar with these notions (analyze / [difference between query and filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html)) which are very important for a good use of ElasticSearch. You can find a good getting started documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search.html).

Your problem is that your "model" field is a string, which by default is analyzed using the **standard** analyzer.

It outputs 2 tokens because of the whitespace in the model name as you can see if you use the _analyze endpoint :

```
GET _analyze?analyzer=standard&text='Serie 5'

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "serie",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "5",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 8,
         "type": "<NUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

On top of that, you're using a  query and though will return all results matching **even partially**. So, you're certainly having the two cars in your results, but the "SERIE 5" car must be the first (as it matches better) than the car "SERIE 3", which is represented by a higher **_score** attribute.

You need to use a [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html) which will return only the documents containing the term value you provided. 
However, as it works on terms, you have to change the mapping of your field to "not_analyzed" like this to keep it as it is :

```
PUT /test/car/_mapping
{
    "properties":{
        "model":{
            "type": "string",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the search request will be something like this (with price criteria as [range filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) and the use of a [and](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html) filter to combine both) :

```
GET /test/car/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "and": {
                  "filters": [
                     {
                     "term": {
                          "model": "Serie 3"
                       }
                     },
                     {
                         "range": {
                            "price": {
                               "from": 500,
                               "to": 70000
                            }
                         }
                     }
                  ]
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query (url_decoded) looks like

```
link:9200/index/_search?from=0&size=130&q=try:'yes' +brand:'BMW' +model:'SERIE 5' +price:[500 TO 700000]
```

I think you are using '+' incorrectely, so that it is doing **or** operation for your query, 
If you want to get with `try:yes`, `brand:BMW` and `model:SERIE 5` then you have to join these query by AND keyword.

like.

```
link:9200/index/_search?from=0&size=130&q=try:'yes' 
AND brand:'BMW' AND model:'SERIE 5' AND price:[500 TO 700000]
```

And you should be aware of [choosing analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) (in mapping of fields), so that things are indexed as you want.

It will work, Thanks

[Reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)